# String manipulation, removing last few characters

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5, string

When I try to remove the last few characters of a string, I get an index out of range error.  I am using the following to remove the characters from the end of the string:

```
objJSONStringBuilder.Remove(objJSONStringBuilder.Length - 1, 6)
```

The string has `<hr />` at the end which I want to remove.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first parameter is the index from where you want to start removing. Use

`objJSONStringBuilder.Remove(objJSONStringBuilder.Length - 6, 6)`

Answer (score 2):

The count goes forwards, not backwards.

```
objJSONStringBuilder.Remove(objJSONStringBuilder.Length - 6, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(StartIndex, Count from start index)
```

You're specifying that the start index should be the last character + 6 characters, that is 6 characters out of the index, thus out of bounds!

You'd rather want to do something like:

```
(length - 7, 6)
```

That would take the last 6 characters if there are 6 or more characters (or else you'll also get out of bounds)

Comment: It's `Count`, not `EndIndex`. Also, `length - 7` goes too far back; it removes the six characters preceding the last character.